# Italic HTML attributes in Vim

Tags: vim, fonts, syntax-highlighting

I'm using the [Operator Mono](http://www.typography.com/blog/introducing-operator) font inside of Vim. However I cannot workout how to make HTML attributes, italic, like in this picture of the Atom editor:

[image]

The Operator Mono font has an italic version which it uses for HTML attributes, making them potentially more readable (depending on your point of view).

So my question...Within my `.vimrc` or within a theme, how can I enable HTML attributes to be italic? Is there a syntax highlighting package that could work?

Comment: I've only tried ` highlight Comment gui=italic` which made the comments look italic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If italic comments are working in vim, you can set HTML attributes in the same way by adding `highlight htmlArg cterm=italic` to your ~/.vimrc. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/74KdI.png) is an example.